# creating new database, what are my tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-connection

I'm having problem doing database.

Here is my two options which I have already done: http://imgur.com/IS30zqu

I have organizations which have these information:

Organization (name, place, address, phone and contact, this is going to be one table)

Organization have also "services" witch is provides. There are four of kind of them (studies, jobs, life organization and rehab).

- In 'life organization' and 'rehab' there is only few choices.

Now my problem starts, I have 'JOB' table and 'STUDIES', they both have 'FIELD' and 'FIELD' has 'TASK'. 'JOB' have more 'TASK' than 'STUDIES'

'JOB' have 3 kind of options which you can chose (it impacts your search result).

for example:
You chose 'JOB' it gives you three choices.
You chose 'SALARY' it gives you 5 choices.
You chose 'MEDICAL' it gives you X choices, depends how many organization provides job with salary in medical field.
Now, it gives you result of search, for example 'nurse'.

I don't know how I do the query or the tables, 'JOB' has more choices than 'STUDIES', so I have to mark them somehow and I'm not sure how. 'JOB' has also three different values and those have to be separately from each other.

Which one is better, option one or option two? Should I do some changes to database or try queries?

Thanks for advance, any help is needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define several extra tables. Presumably an organisation can provide more than one service, so you need one table which defines a 'service' and one 'join table' which joins an organisation to a service. From here, your terminology becomes a bit hazy, but as I understand it, you have 'choices' (or sub-service), each of which can only be connected to one service. Also, organisations tend to have more than one contact person and each contact can have more than one phone number. I am assuming that a contact is connected only to one organisation (not necessarily true).

So your table structure becomes

```
ORGANISATIONS
id
name
address

CONTACTS
id 
name
organisation id

CONTACTPHONE
id
contact id
type of phone
phonenum

SERVICES
id
name

ORGSERVICES
organisation id
services id 

SUBSERVICES
id
name
services id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for late answer.

Comment: @Tsukirai: if what I have written answers your question, then 'accept' the answer (click on the green arrow)